# more with a comparative degree

Tags: adjectives

We use 'more' when we use the second degree of the words with multiple syllable such as "beautiful" becomes "more beautiful". We don't use 'more' with words like rich and hard. We say: richer, harder. We also don't use 'more' for the second degree of words like: good==> better

> Can we say the following:
>
> More better
>
> More richer

Comment: _Better_ and _richer_ are already comparatives, so there is no need to use _more_.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "more better".

There is some limited use of this but it is mostly confined to young children.  "More better" would be considered an error in most contexts, especially if it was used to mean "better".

You can intensify "better" or "richer" with adverbs like "much":

> Bill Gates is much richer than I am.